# How do i add padding after last item in a grouping in listview? (xaml)

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

Im trying to add some padding/space after the last item in a grouping in a listview. Like my image below How do i achieve that?

![https://imgur.com/s4yx99b] "listview"

```
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" BackgroundColor="#2D3334" CornerRadius="0" >
                    <Frame Margin="0,15,0,0" Padding="0,8,0,15" BackgroundColor="#324458" CornerRadius="0" >
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  TextColor="white" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#2D3334" Margin="0,3,0,3"  TextColor="#C4ced8" Text="LPic" />
                            <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  BackgroundColor="#2D3334" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  TextColor="#C4ced8" Margin="0,3,0,3"  Text="30. SEP" />

                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some pixels in RowHeight(row normal height + amount of padding you want) property of your listview then add `VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"` to your Frame tag

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, I see there are three label in ListView header, so you want the last item to be a little away from the screen on the right? If yes, I suggest you can take a look the following code:

Firstly, please add the enough space for the third ColumnDefinition, then make label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand".

```
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame
                            Margin="0,15,0,0"
                            Padding="0,8,0,15"
                            BackgroundColor="#324458">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Margin="0,3,0,3"
                                    BackgroundColor="#2D3334"
                                    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                    Text="LPic"
                                    TextColor="#C4ced8"
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

                                <Label
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    Text="{Binding Heading}"
                                    TextColor="white"
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                                <Label
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                    Margin="0,3,0,3"
                                    BackgroundColor="#2D3334"
                                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                    Text="30. SEP"
                                    TextColor="#C4ced8"
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```